# JQuery File Upload action=server/php

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, file-upload

I was trying to get to work a [JQuery File Uploader](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) but I ran into difficulties. 
I have copied and pasted all files and folders they have got their into my rails project folder.
But the "Add files"-Button doesnt work. I can select the files but nothing happens afterwords.
I have studied the code and found :

```
<!-- The file upload form used as target for the file upload widget -->
    <form id="fileupload" action="server/php/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <!-- The fileupload-buttonbar contains buttons to add/delete files and start/cancel the upload -->
```

An action called "action="server/php". They dont have controllers with such an action, one what they have with such name is a folder [/server/php](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/tree/master/server/php).So the action correspons to a folder. I donwloaded it as well and placed in my rails project. I dont want to upload everything to a server, I want to look first if it worls with simplier "rails s". But I have no idea how I can link

```
action="server/php"
```

in

```
<form id="fileupload" action="server/php/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

to my server/php folder.

I would be really grateful if somebody helps me to deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

I ran in a similiar problem,but on a PHP-site.

try

```
action="server/php/index.php"
```

Comment: No, it still does not work. I guess because rails doesnt understand where it should search for a server/php folder. So I have to link server/php/index.php with a folder in rails project but I do not know how.